# Range checking using bitwise operators in C

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, bitwise-and, bitwise-xor

I am working on this method, but I am restricted to using ONLY these operators: `<<`, `>>`, `!`, `~`, `&`, `^` and `|`

I want to do above range checking using bitwise operator, is it possible in a one-line statement?

```
void OnNotifyCycleStateChanged(int cycleState)
{
   // if cycleState is = 405;
   if(cycleState >= 400 && cycleState <=7936)  // range check 
   {
   // do work ....
   }
}
```

Example:

```
bool b1 = (cycleState & 0b1111100000000); // 0b1111100000000 = 7936
```

Is this the right way to do that?

Comment: The code doesn’t make sense. It says it checks for 405, then it assigns 400 to the variable instead of comparing. And if it is 400, or 405, it definitely is less than 7936 so the second comparison is not needed. Could you please clarify the issue a bit more?

Comment: Your `if()` has an assignment. Is that intended? Even if was equality comparison it would never make sense since `cycleState` of 400 is already less than 7936.

Comment: by mistake, I wrote that

Comment: CHECK I UPDATE CODE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool b1 = CheckCycleStateWithinRange(cycleState, 0b110010000, 0b1111100000000); // Note *: 0b110010000 = 400 and 0b1111100000000 = 7936

bool CheckCycleStateWithinRange(int cycleState, int minRange, int maxRange) const
{
   return ((IsGreaterThanEqual(cycleState, minRange) && IsLessThanEqual(cycleState, maxRange)) ? true : false );
}

int IsGreaterThanEqual(int cycleState, int limit) const
{
   return ((limit + (~cycleState + 1)) >> 31 & 1) | (!(cycleState ^ limit));
}

int IsLessThanEqual(int cycleState, int limit) const
{
   return !((limit + (~cycleState + 1)) >> 31 & 1) | (!(cycleState ^ limit));
}
```